# How can I use :not() with nth-child to select all Items that aren't the 1st, 2nd, or 3rd Item

Tags: css

So I have a blog roll and the first 3 blog posts get unique styling but the rest of them all have their own styles that should match. So I need to add styles for the rest of the blog feed while skipping the first 3 with the selector.

Will I be writing 3 rules,

```
.blog-card:not(:nth-child(1)) {
    classes here
}

.blog-card:not(:nth-child(2)) {
    classes here
}

.blog-card:not(:nth-child(3)) {
    classes here
}
```

or is there a better way to approach this

Edit: because this was marked as duplicate I have to admit that like a dummy I tried to use the code from the question of the original post not the answers...

Comment: `.blog-card:not(:nth-child(-n + 3))` ?

Comment: Thank you, I knew there had to be an easier way. Can you explain the `(-n + 3)` part?

Comment: `.blog-card:nth-child(3) ~ .blog-card` would be less syntactically-cool, but (arguably) more legible; though it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @DavidThomas that also looks cool to me, can you explain what `~` does in css?

Comment: MDN has excellent documentation: [general sibling combinator: `~`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator).